# es6 modules: import specific-functions as aName

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'd like to import specific functions from another module. But I faced naming collision: I have similar function names in my importing file. I'd like to do something like this:

```js
// exporterFile.js

export {
    set,
    get,
    has,
    foo,
    bar,
}

// implementation code for set, get, etc.
```

```js
// importerFile.js

import {get, set} as exporter from "exporterFile.js"

function get() {
    // some code and call set from exporter
    exporter.set(something)
}
```

I know I could `import * as exporter from "exporterFile.js"` but it lacks readability and does not show what methods (functions) I am using from the exporter file.

Also, I know I could `import {get as exporterGet, set as exporterSet} from "exporterFile.js"` but it is not so readable.

Is there an elegant, clear, readable way to import selected functions from a module without naming collision? If not, what is the best practice and approach and suggestion: readability is very important, tree-shaking is a consideration as well.

Comment: nope that's the way it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no alternatives to the two ways you already mentioned. Readability is subjective, but both `exporterGet()` and `exporter.get()` are good choices that are common. If you explicitly want to list all the used function in the `import` statement itself, you will have to give them individual aliases. Tree shaking tools will be able to handle both formats.